# What does (append = false) mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a silly question...I tried searching everywhere and couldn't find what I was looking for...what does `(append = false)` mean in javascript?

```
myImages(append = false) {
    if (n>10) {
           console.log("Pass");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failed");
    }   
};
```

Comment: [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: In this particular function it means nothing at all because the function parameter is not used. Generally it's a way of assigning default values for un-passed function parameters.

Comment: Thanks I understand!